# How set the initial value for a tkinter Scale widget in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I want to initialize the value of a `Scale` widget to `2`. How can I do this? Because I used a grid, `.set` won't work properly.

Here is my code:

```
Scale(self, command=self.onMove, movesvariable=self.var, from_=1, to=10,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=500,tickinterval=0.5, resolution=0.1, cursor = 'hand2 ').grid(columnspan ='200',rowspan = '4',sticky= W)
```

Comment: _"because I use a grid, .set won't word [sic] properly"_. The proper solution is to move the call to `.grid` on a separate line. There's simply no advantage to doing it all in one line.

Comment: i have fixed this problem, but when i enlarge the widget, it wont fix the size of it, Do you have any good solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change this to two lines:

```
yourScale = Scale(self, command=self.onMove, movesvariable=self.var, from_=1, to=10,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=500,tickinterval=0.5, resolution=0.1, cursor = 'hand2 ')
yourScale.grid(columnspan ='200',rowspan = '4',sticky= W)
```

`.grid()` returns `None`; calling it after Scale like you've done won't return a Scale object like you would expect, it will return a Nonetype. Implementing this small change should allow you to use `.set` on whatever variable you store the Scale object in. (`yourScale` in this example)

As an aside: You might want to remove the `set` tag in your question: `set` references a data structure, not the set function from Tkinter.

Comment: i have fixed this problem, but when i enlarge the widget, it wont fix the size of it, Do you have any good solutions to this problem?

Comment: Do you mean the scale doesn't get larger to accommodate for the enlarged widget, or it **does** get larger and you don't want it to?